# Array output or json output without quotes

Tags: php, arrays, json

How i can output my array without quotes on this situation

```
for($i=1; $i <= date("d"); $i++) { $days[] = $i;    }
echo json_encode($days); // ouput [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

This first on is fine, but on the second one

```
for($i=1;$i <= date("d"); $i++) {
        $Sql = "SELECT COUNT(Stats_Clicks) AS Total FROM tabstats WHERE DAY(Stats_Date) = $i
                AND MONTH(Stats_Date) = $month
                AND YEAR(Stats_Date) = $year 
                ";
        $Query = mysql_query($Sql,$Conn) or die (mysql_error($Conn));
        $Rs = mysql_fetch_array($Query);    

        $clicks[] = $Rs['Total'];
    }
    echo json_encode($clicks);
```

json output returns this

```
["1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
```

i need this without quotes on this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need cast to integer.

```
$clicks[] = (int)$Rs['Total'];
```

Comment: unbelievable, 2 hours searching for a solution, arrays, vectors etc etc... thanks dude, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
$clicks[] = (int) $Rs['Total'];
```

Answer (score 1):

try array_map with intval function

like this:

```
echo json_encode(array_map("intval",($Rs['Total'])));
```

example:

```
print_r(json_encode(array_map("intval",array("1","2","3"))));
=> [1,2,3]
```